# How to customize the "Save File" dialog

Tags: 15.10, gtk, filemanager, dialog

I can't remember exactly which configuration file I've modified, but the next time I booted my computer, I found that I unintendedly added the `sources.list.d` folder to the "Places" list of the "Save File" dialog.

[image]

Now I want to remove this folder shortcut from the "Places" list, but the "Remove Bookmark" button (the `−` symbol) is disabled.

Does anyone know how to customize the "Places" list of the "Save File" dialog?